# Nginx Rewite - Matching End Urls not working

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, regex

Trying to redirect urls like these:

```
http://example.com/vehicles/cars/author/xyz
http://example.com/plane/author/xyz
```

to these:

```
http://example.com/profile/xyz
```

I tried this Nginx Rewrite, but its not picking up the match and redirecting:

```
rewrite ^/author/(.*)$     http://example.com/profile/$1 last;
```

What have I got wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^/author/(*)$` means that it starts with `/author/`. The URLs you want to rewrite don't start with `/author/`. You need something like this:

```
rewrite ^/.*/author/(.*)$ http://example.com/profile/$1 last;
```

But I think this is better and probably more robust:

```
rewrite /author/([^/]+)/?$ http://example.com/profile/$1 last;
```

Comment: Aha.... that makes sense. I thought `^` starts the match from anywhere. Thank you @AntonisChrisofides

Comment: `^` is the standard regular expression for the start of line